# Find Distinct Element Counts from Array in CUDA

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

I have a large `int` array that I instantiate in a parallel manner. It is effectively a 2D array:

```
#define SUB_ARR_SIZE 500
#define ARR_SIZE 100000

__device__ int arr[ARR_SIZE*SUB_ARR_SIZE];
```

I fill this `arr` parallelly and have no issues with that. I am wondering how to create a new array of structs that update, in a parallel manner:

```
typedef struct {
   int elem;
   int count;  
} arr_elem;

__device__ int distinct_arr[NUMBER_OF_DISTINCT_ELEMS];
__device__ int distinct_arr_count = 0;
```

My issue is that `NUMBER_OF_DISTINCT_ELEMS` is unknown and I'm not quite sure how to handle such a problem without just iterating through each element in `arr` and iterating through every element in `distinct_arr` to see if it is present. So something like:

```
__global__ void kernel() {
    if (threadIdx.x == 0 && blockIdx.x == 0) {
        for (int i=0;i<ARR_SIZE*SUB_ARR_SIZE;i++) {
            int found = 0;
            for (int n=0;n<distinct_arr_count;n++) {
                if (distinct_arr[n].elem == arr[i]) {
                    distinct_arr[n].count++;
                    found = 1;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                arr_elem e = {.elem = arr[i], .count = 1};
                distinct_arr[distinct_arr_count] = e;
                distinct_arr_count++;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Yes, I am aware that this code is horrendous for parallel processing (and anything for that matter), but I haven't really found a way to do this same operation in a parallel manner. Are there any tried and true methods for finding such distinct arrays in CUDA?

Comment: I seem to have found some relevant info here:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/find-unique-elements-in-array/6528/2

Comment: This type of operation is basically histogram calculation. See the marked duplicate for a robust approach.

Comment: This seems to be the answer I was looking for, thank you
https://web.archive.org/web/20111124025224/http://www.moderngpu.com/sort/hist.html